# Spring boot with Gradle "Application failed to start" The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle

Tags: java, spring, gradle

Any ideas what is the issue? This happened after upgrading Gradle, Spring framework and all dependencies to the latest version. Tried by using @Lazy on Beans but still getting an error. Please check the uploaded images for a better understanding. Thanks in advance.[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7o9r.png)

**JwtRequestFilter file**

```
@Autowired
private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    String username = null;
    String jwtToken = null;
    // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get only the Token
    if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
        try {
            username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
        }
    } else {
        logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
    }

    //Once we get the token validate it.
    if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

        UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set authentication
        if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                    .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
            // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the Spring Security Configurations successfully.
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

}

**JwtUserDetailsService file**

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private RoleRepository roleRepository;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (!user.isPresent()) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            user.get().getUsername(),
            user.get().getPassword(),
            getAuthorities(user.get())
    );
}

public User getUser(){
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
            .getPrincipal();
    String username = userDetails.getUsername();
    return userRepository.findByUsername(username).get();
}

private Set<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user) {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
    user.getAuthorities().forEach(role -> {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
    });

    return authorities;
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java file**

```
@Autowired
private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

@Autowired
private CorsFilter corsFilter;

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/api/user/login");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

    httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/user/login", "/api/user/login", "/management/users/register", "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("Admin")
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("User")

            // all other requests need to be authenticated
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().
            // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
            // store user's state.
                    exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Bean
CorsFilter getCorsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addExposedHeader("Authorization, Content-Type, Error");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your problem is due to your use of property injection.

Use constructor injection instead (everywhere), and your problem will likely go away.

Comment: Thank you GreyBeardedGeek but still having the same issue after changing to constructor injection. Can you please check here: https://pastebin.com/XgS9jtve
Thanks in advance.